# Executable Unix script cannot be found by which command

Tags: linux, bash, unix, system-administration

I have a Unix bash script written by a former teammate that must be in my `PATH`, though I can't find it by manual inspection (see below).  I can however execute it anywhere by just typing

```
$ my_script
```

I would like to view and edit this script. However, when I try to find it via the `which` command, I get a blank response. Return code indicates an error:

```
$ which my_script
$ echo $?
1
```

And yet, I can run the script.  I manually combed my `PATH` and could not find it.  Honestly, I have not encountered anything like this in 20+ years.  Is there any other command besides `which`, and/or ways such a script could be hidden?

Comment: Try to run find command, to search your "/" for the given file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To determine the *type* of *any command* callable from the shell, **use the [`type` builtin](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/type.html)**.

In your case, since the presumptive *script* turned to be a *shell function*, you would have seen (assuming `bash`):

```
$ type my_script  # Bash: option -t would output just 'function`
my_script is a function
my_script () 
{                
...               # The function's definition
```

From there - as you did - you can examine the profile (e.g., `~/.bash_profile`) and / or initialization scripts (e.g., `~/.bashrc`) to determine where the function was sourced.

*Caveat*: The function signature output by `type` is normalized to the `<name> ()` form - even if you defined the function as `function <name>`

**In `bash` you can even find out *directly* where a given function was defined** (tip of the hat to [this superuser.com answer](https://superuser.com/questions/144772/finding-the-definition-of-a-bash-function) and [Charles Duffy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14122/charles-duffy) for inspiring me to find it and coming up with the most succinct form):

```
$ (shopt -s extdebug; declare -F my_func)
my_func 112 /Users/jdoe/.bashrc   # sample output
```

`112` is the line number inside the script indicated.

Comment: Might be worth extending this to cover finding the source file and line for any defined function.

Comment: Ah, the `type` command was new to me, and unfortunately I was using the `-pa` options recommended in the other answer, which would in fact hide the very thing we were meant to discover.

Comment: `(shopt -s extdebug; declare -F my_script)` will, in this case, output something like `my_script 10 /home/youruser/.bashrc`, giving the file and line number where `my_script` was defined... ahh, I see you found that too. :)

Comment: @CharlesDuffy: Your formulation is better, thanks - updated.

Answer (score 1):

Try
1. `type my_script`
or
2. `find / -name my_script -print`

Note that `find` will throw a lot of permission errors if you run this as a normal user. You can run it as root to avoid that or pipe STDERR to `/dev/null`

Comment: Better: `find / ... 2>/dev/null`, since you're only interested in things visible to the current user.

Comment: `type` is very much the right thing, but `type -pa` less so; it will contain no output if (as is the case here) the command is not in fact external. Also, escalating privileges of `find` to root is bad practice -- the shell can't possibly be using a command from somewhere the current user can't read, so there's no point to searching in those places.

Comment: Well...I assumed he knew it is a file and not a function...Bad assumption on my part. Editing my answer now.

Answer (score 1):

Found it.  I am leaving the question and answer in case someone else runs into a similar situation.  I am marking a different answer as the final answer as it contains some more useful tools for finding what I found (see below).

### Summary

The "script" was actually a `bash` function that had been written into a sourced `.` file.

### Details

The account's `.bashrc` file was sourcing another `.` file:

```
. ~/.other-dot-file
```

In that other `.` file was the bash function called `my_script`.

```
function my_script {
....
}
```

Since this was sourced, the function could be executed from the command line, mimicking the behavior of a full-fledged script.  There is no other code that calls this function - it is purely meant to be called from the command line, as if it were a script.

This willful obscurity is part of the reason the author is no longer with us.

Comment: As an aside, the `function` keyword is a bashism, making code incompatible with baseline POSIX sh without adding any significant utility; the POSIX-compliant way to define a function is `my_script() { ...; }`, with the parenthesis added and no `function` preceding.